# vk api python bot отправить разные сообщения разным людям при том что они пишут одно и тоже сообщение

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api, бот

У меня есть бот для беседы VK и матерящаяся компания мне нужно сделать если (есть 5 человек) Лёха сматерился ему прибавлялась единица к переменной, а если сматерился Матвей то ему прибавляется единица и раз в 24 часа отправлялось сообщение сколько кто раз сматерился. Как это правильно сделать если есть возможность желательно через if с объяснением т.к. я в этом новичок или ссылку на статью хотя-бы с похожим вопросом

```
import random, vk_api, vk
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import requests
import sys
import time
import threading
import json


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='ТОКЕН')
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 204434733)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
Lslongpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
Lsvk = vk_session.get_api()



def bot():

    Lsvk.messages.send(
    user_id = 496658805,
    message = "Бот запущен!",
    random_id = get_random_id()
    )

    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if 'БОТ' in str(event) or 'Бот' in str(event) or 'бот' in str(event):
                if event.from_chat:
                    if event.from_user:
                        vk.messages.send(
                        key = ('b0409379fb3b81632ee943deb2e99280c53dd520'),          #ВСТАВИТЬ ПАРАМЕТРЫ
                        server = ('https://lp.vk.com/wh204434733'),
                        ts=('1'),
                        random_id = get_random_id(),
                        message='Привет! Я бот DDRX5 теперь ты можешь вызывать меня по имени!',
                        chat_id = event.chat_id
                        )





bot = threading.Thread(target=bot)
bot.start()

#################################################################

except:
    Lsvk.messages.send(
        user_id=496658805,
        message="Бот выключен :( ",
        random_id=get_random_id()
      )
```

Вот весь мой бот

Вот всё так написал а user_id подчёркнут красным

```
import random, vk_api, vk
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import requests
import sys
import time
import threading
import json

from collections import defaultdict
user_by_counter = defaultdict(int)

try:




vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='')
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 204434733)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
Lslongpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
Lsvk = vk_session.get_api()



def bot():

    Lsvk.messages.send(
    user_id = 496658805,
    message = "Бот запущен!",
    random_id = get_random_id()
    )

    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if 'БОТ' in str(event) or 'Бот' in str(event) or 'бот' in str(event):
                if event.from_chat:
                    user_by_counter[user_id] += 1
                    vk.messages.send(
                        key = 'b0409379fb3b81632ee943deb2e99280c53dd520',          #ВСТАВИТЬ ПАРАМЕТРЫ
                        server = ('https://lp.vk.com/wh204434733'),
                        ts=('1'),
                        random_id = get_random_id(),
                        message='Привет! Я бот DDRX5 теперь ты можешь вызывать меня по имени!',
                        chat_id = event.chat_id
                        )
```

Comment: 150 строк это нестрашно, добавьте код в вопрос, т.к. он должен быть самодостаточным. Пока непонятно в чем у вас проблема. А так, заведите базу данных, например sqlite, в ней храните в таблице пользователя, дата и счетчик. При обработке сообщений, проверяйте их на маты (лучше каким-то лексическим анализатором типа pymorph, т.к. простой проверкой слов можно кучу ложных срабатываний получить, типа потре**бля**ть). останется сделать отправку сообщений в указанное время, можно использовать `schedule`, запущенный в отдельном потоке/отдельном скрипте, который из базы вытащит за текущий день счетчики

Comment: окей щас добавлю код

Comment: мне интересно а можно ли это через if типа добавить if user_id == 123456789: то Lexa =+ 1

Comment: Можно, но при новых участниках или при других аккаунтах придется код править. Кст, в вопросе лучше оставить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы ничего лишнего не отвлекало тех, кто захочет помочь. Кст, а зачем после указания параметров вы значения в круглые скобки ставите? Это ведь ничего не дает и мешает чтению кода?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/144578/ вот в этой статье было написано в круглых скобках а я как мало знакомый в VK-api решил делать всё также

Comment: Похоже, автор указывая `('')` отметил те места, куда еще нужно значения поставить (другие параметры без них были), все-равно это странно выглядит :) Поэтому смело удаляйте скобки ;)

Comment: Понял, спасибо, а вы не могли-бы скинуть пример, я просто убрал скобки в key, server, ts, random_id и бот не читал и не присылал сообщения, бот без этих скобок не работает

Comment: И вы не могли-бы расписать про возможность сделать задачу через if со всеми 'но' если можно

Comment: Бот без скобок будет работать, смотрите `key = ('b0409379fb3b81632ee943deb2e99280c53dd520'),` и `key = 'b0409379fb3b81632ee943deb2e99280c53dd520',` это тоже самое. Самое простое и без базы, делаете словарь через `user_by_counter = defaultdict(int)` (`from collections import defaultdict`, создаете его в глобальной области), где ключом будет `user_id`, а значением счетчик, на каждый случай мата увеличиваете счетчик `user_by_counter[user_id] += 1` в конце дня подводите итоги, рассылаете статистику и очищаете словарь (`user_by_counter.clear()`)

Comment: Я конечно извиняюсь может тупой вопрос задаю, можете расписать эти действия подробней + как добавлять единицу именно тому человеку кто написал мат, а не всем

Comment: `user_id` это ведь тот кто написал сообщение, как там могут быть оказаться все участники? Добавьте к вопросу минимальный пример по этой проблеме, чтобы любой мог запустить, так будет проще помочь

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/PUNr1_PpDyJy-A https://disk.yandex.ru/i/s_-n-uQ8hxZDpg

Comment: фото залил на диск так как не понял как их в коментарии залить

Comment: Нужно в **вопрос**, а не в комментарии. Для правки вопроса есть кнопка `править` под ним

Comment: всё залил в вопрос фото, скорее всего я где-то ступил

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Простите, сделал в вопросе изменения

Comment: `user_id` ведь нужно заполнять, берите его из `event`, посмотрел в примерах библиотеки, нужно брать от `event.obj.from_id`: https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/4755517fe94bc747cd2e032b53f8c41ddd45e533/examples/bot_longpoll.py#L23

Comment: Понял, спасибо пробую

Comment: Всё заработало, спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста :) если разобрались, то оформите сами ответ с решением проблемы :) Тут ниже есть кнопка что-то вроде "Ответить на собственный вопрос"

Comment: понял сделаю обязательно, но хотелосьбы узнать на счёт анализа мата в переменной str(event) помимо pymorph так как проект закрыт как я знаю. Или я могу создать на эту тему новый вопрос

Comment: Тема непростая, лучше сделайте отдельный вопрос, а так есть другое проект: https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сделал отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо в начале после всех import на новой строке написать `from collections import defaultdict`
а на второй `user_by_counter = defaultdict(int)`

а вот что должно быт в отправке сообщения, точнее как она должно выглядеть

```
 for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if 'Текст от пользователя' in str(event):
                    if event.from_chat:
                        user_id = event.obj.from_id
                        user_by_counter[user_id] += 1
                        vk.messages.send(
                            key = (''),          #ВСТАВИТЬ ПАРАМЕТРЫ
                            server = (''),
                            ts=(''),
                            random_id = get_random_id(),
                            message='ответ пользователю' ,
                            chat_id = event.chat_id
                            )
```